# Why does `ping` succeed while telnet failed from inside a container residing in an docker overlay network?

Tags: docker, networking

I created an overlay network in a host and I start a container A in the overlay network.

I start another container B which resides in a bridge network of the same host machine(the host machine is with a LAN IP, while container B is with a VIP in the bridge network), which is listening on port 8848 and the port is exposed. Now I can telnet to container B with either LAN_IP:8848 or VIP:8848 from terminal of the host machine.

From inside container A, I can successfully ping the IP of the host machine LAN IP as well as the VIP of container B in the bridge network. But I can't telnet to the container B from inside A, either by LAN_IP:8848 or VIP:8848. What is wrong?

Comment: Ping and telnet use completely different protocols.

Comment: @RonMaupin yes, I know, but why telnet doesn't work in my scenario? firewall forbids outgoing connection to that port?

Comment: You have not included nearly enough information to be able to answer that.

Comment: @RonMaupin container B is listening on port 8848, and `telnet to it` on the host machine is successful, but `telnet to it from inside container A` failed

Comment: I do not understand how this is a programming question. You should be asking this on the correct SE site, such as [sf] for a business network.